# How to keep enum values most efficiently in database for Java apps?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, enums

I implement enum classes in my entities as shown below:

***enum:***

```
public enum Difficulty {

    EASY,
    MODERATE,
    HARD;
}
```

***entity:***

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Difficulty difficulty;

}
```

However, these enum values are kept in PostgreSQL database table as `EASY`, `MODERATE` or `HARD` instead of a numeric values e.g. 1, 2, 3. When I need to use enum instead of creating a lookup table for this `Difficulty` enum, it there a better approach for Java apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the value in`@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)` then the ordinal values will be written into the database

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated
    private Difficulty difficulty;
}
```

But keep in mind, that reordering or adding a new enum value in the middle will breaks the functionality, because the number is mapped to an other in enum value

Comment: Good point. But I am wondering 2 issues at this point: **1.** I think it is better to keep numeric values for saving space in database, right? **2.** But would it be a problem in the future when I add new numeric value between two numeric values instead of at the end of the se values? What would you suggest? And which approach do Java developers generally follow?

Comment: I just seen your apply and you also mentioned what I asked. Then, which approach do Java developers generally follow?

Comment: It is oppinion based. I personally prefer the string

Comment: on the other hand you can't rename your enums when using `STRING`, right? For this reason, both options would be preferred depending on situations. Right?

Comment: But if you rename the string you will get an exception when running. if you use the int value, you simply map to a wrong value

Comment: And, when we want to use numeric value, I think we should replace the annotation with `@Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)` instead of completely remove for readability. What do you think amigo?

Comment: We think the same things at the same time, when I post a new comment I see you mentioned exactly about the same issue :))  What about my last comment?

Comment: You are partly right. updated my answer. The value `ORDINAL` is the default, so you only need the annotation

Comment: The last question: STRING keeps more space than ORDINAL, right? Think of there are millions of records having the value of `EASY` instead of `1`. What do you think for this issue?